# float and round off in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I am working on a long file whose columns are like this:

```
0.028488    35.3465833928   0.223905932998  0.128418942246  23  51  50.23   -27 57  47.4
```

I have to copy the first 3 columns, work on the last 3 and write the results in a file. This is is part of the code:

```
with open(file) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        a = float(line.split()[1])
        b = float(line.split()[2])
        c = float(line.split()[3])
        deg = float(line.split()[7])
        min = float(line.split()[8])
        sec = float(line.split()[9])
        #I have to calculate radiants from deg, min, sec (and I have some phase issues: that is why I write pi/2 - ...)
        if (deg != 0.):
            rad = math.pi/2. - deg/math.fabs(deg) *(deg + min/60. + sec/3600.) * math.pi/180.
        else:
            if (min !=0):
                rad = math.pi/2. - min/math.fabs(min) * (min/60. + sec/3600.) * math.pi /180.
            else:
                rad = math.pi/2. - sec/math.fabs(sec) * (sec/3600.) *math.pi/180.
        vec = [[a, b, c, rad]]
        np.savetxt(fout,vec)
```

This is what python writes on the file:

```
2.848799999999999900e-02 3.534658339280000000e+01 2.239059329979999900e-01 7.016950813538869200e-01
```

as you can see, since a,b,c are floats, python has some difficulties in rewritng them and I think this causes some problems in my code (round off maybe).

How can I avoid it, if I can?

Edit:corrected a (horrible) typo...

I use python 2.6

Comment: What was your expected output?

Comment: The first 3 columns should just be copied

Comment: I'd suggest splitting the line with `values = list(map(float, line.split()))` followed by `a, b, c, _, _, _, deg, min, sec = values[:9]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a format string to `numpy.savetxt` with the `fmt` parameter to specify how you want the output formatted.

```
np.savetxt(fout, vec, fmt="%.2f")
```

This should yield something like this:

```
35.35 0.22 0.13 1.12
```

This doesn't do rounding, but it does truncate the number of decimal places that are printed out. You can change the number of decimal places that you want displayed by changing the format string.